# Звуковая схема слова ПОЯС

Tags: фонетика, учебное-задание

Помогите составить звуковую схему к слову *пояс*.

Comment: @Тамара007, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Это в каком классе? В 1? Во втором? Посмотрите печатную рабочую тетрадь ребёнка. Если звуковая схема в виде цветных квадратиков,то красный квадратик - гласный, синий - твёрдый согласный, зелёный - мягкий согласный.

По-яс [по-йас] - синий, красный/зелёный, красный, синий.

Если квадратики, кружочки, треугольники, посмотрите, что они обозначают, и закрасьте их так, как в тетради

**Обновление**

Здесь буква Я обозначает 2 звука - й+а, значит, звуки:

п - твёрдый согл., о - ударный гласный, й - мягкий согласный, а - безударный гласный, с - твёрдый согласный.

Да, 4 буквы и 5 звуков.

Comment: Это первый класс.Там без квадратиков. Там нужно звуковую схему составить.

 Пример: Слово Ветки. Значит схема звучит так:    1 буква - мягкая ударная, 2 буква - ударная гласная, 3 буква - твердая согласная и так далее.

А со словом Пояс я что то запуталась )

Получается, в этом слове 4 буквы и 5 звуков?

Comment: Обновила ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ !

Comment: Ух как интересно! Хочу снова в первый класс! Это их так учат, что существуют ударные согласные? ("Слово Ветки. Значит схема звучит так: 1 буква - мягкая ударная") А в слове "пояс" буква  Я обозначает, по-моему, не  й+а, а скорее что-то среднее между йе и йи. Я так слышу, но может быть первоклассникам полагается слышать иначе.

Comment: А Вы бы хотели ещё и редуцированные ввести в 1 классе? Видите, что мама сама путается в звуках -буквах, согласных-гласных, а уж ребёнок и подавно. Достаточно и того, что пока они будут знать, что в сильной позиции Я=Й+А, а уж о позиционной мене узнают позже, иначе и этого не усвоят.Мы в их возрасте и этого не понимали.

Comment: Зато быстро учились читать и писать. Теперь понятно, почему они книжек не читают - им же тяжело, их в первом классе не чтению учили, а какой-то надуманной теории. Их и винить-то нельзя - наоборот: ордена давать тем, кто все-таки читать-писать научился.